# Is this any different from normal integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers

This may be a really stupid question, but I've never formally learned the answer to this question.

We know that if $F'(x)=f(x)$ and if $a, b\in\Bbb R$, then 
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$$
But what if $a,b\in\Bbb C\setminus \Bbb R$? Assuming that $F$ is defined and converges for such $a,b\in\Bbb C\setminus \Bbb R$, is 
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)\text{?}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $F$ is holomorphic in a domain $U$, with $F'=f$, then for each contour $\gamma$ inside $U$,
$$\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz=F(b)-F(a)$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the start and end points of $\gamma$.

This is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for holomorphic functions, and is in
all texts on complex analysis.

Comment: So $\gamma$ is just a complex 'interval'?

Comment: $\gamma$ is a *contour*. The concept of interval only makes sense for $\mathbf{R}$. If you think of $\mathbf{C}$ being similar to $\mathbf{R}^2$ you can see between two end points there is no concept of interval. Instead there are infinitely many paths/contours connecting them. The above states that, for special complex functions, it doesn't matter which path you take